# Process not listed on "ps -ef" (AIX 7.1)

Tags: unix, aix, ps

I have an unusual problem involving the output from the `ps -ef` command on AIX 7.1.

A shell script monitors processes by parsing this output. I've noticed on two occasions a process (a Perl program) was omitted from this list. Everything I've read on the subject says this is not possible. The program in question starts via crontab at 6am and runs until 11pm, when it self terminates. I checked the output of `ps -ef` immediately after being omitted by the monitor script, and it displays:

```
user  1249864  9569338   0 06:00:00   -  0:19 /usr/bin/perl -w /path/to/omittedProgram.pl
```

... which means it's the same process that was started at 6am. The program did not terminate, then restart.

What is causing it to be omitted from the `ps -ef` output?

Edit: This is the program that examines the output of `ps -ef`, which has been running successfully for about five years. I've only noticed this problem twice, but both have been in the last 2 months:

```
# set global variables
PROCESS_FILE=/tmp/processList.txt
TEMP_FILE=/tmp/greppedProcesses.tmp
BOX=`uname -n`
DATE=`date`
EMAIL_LIST="Support@email.address"

# Get list of running processes
ps -ef > $PROCESS_FILE

checkProcess() {
  PROCESS_NAME=$1
  PROCESS_ABBREVIATION=$2
  PROCESS_COUNT=$3
  UNIQUE_PROCESS_IDENTIFIER=$4

  GREPPED_LINES=$TEMP_FILE-$PROCESS_ABBREVIATION
  grep $UNIQUE_PROCESS_IDENTIFIER $PROCESS_FILE | grep -v grep > $GREPPED_LINES
  NUM=`cat $GREPPED_LINES | wc -l`
  if [[ $NUM -ne $PROCESS_COUNT ]]
     # Incorrect number of processes running!
     then MESSAGE=`printf "The \"$PROCESS_NAME\" process count is %1d, but it should be $PROCESS_COUNT!!!" $NUM`
          echo "Monitor - starting on $DATE\n\n$MESSAGE\n\n`cat $GREPPED_LINES`" | mail -s "Problem with $PROCESS_NAME on $BOX" $EMAIL_LIST
  fi
  # Delete the temp file
  rm $GREPPED_LINES
}

checkProcess "Full Name of Program" "Program Abbreviation" <expected number of processes running> "Unique string to identify program in ps output"
checkProcess ... (for other processes) ...

exit 0
```

Comment: The problem might be a bug in your monitor script; if so, you need to include the script in your question. If not, it's probably not a programming question, and would be better suited to [unix.se].

Comment: I hope you're not using the "fancy" quotes found in your Q subject line `“ps -ef”` in your script :-) Are you doing the std `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $pid` thing? Maybe you're intersecting with other `greps` in the process table. Unfortuately, AIX doesn't have `pgrep` (or not std) which might help. Good luck.

Comment: I added the code that examines the output. I'm not using fancy quotes. I write the output from `ps -ef` to a file before examining it to avoid command conflicts. Ya, I checked to see if our install of AIX uses `pgrep`, but alas, it does not.

Comment: Comment the line `rm $GREPPED_LINES` and check that file. Are the lines like you expected? Can you process that file with a stand-alone script?

Comment: I've added code to keep the contents of `$GREPPED LINES`, but I haven't been able to duplicate this problem since the addition.

Comment: This happened again, and I have the output of the `ps -ef` command this time. That process is not listed. The "disappearing" program logs info every ten seconds, and during the time the `ps -ef` command was issued, the logs show activity at the exact same second:

The Perl program that issues the `ps -ef` command:
`One Monitor to Rule Them All - starting on Thu Jun 15 10:47:01 PDT 2017`

The output from the "missing" program:
`10:47:01 - PEM_Beat: SUCCESS! ELAPSED TIME: 26 ms (rc=0)`
`10:47:01 - MM_Beat: SUCCESS! ELAPSED TIME: 35 ms (rc=0)`

I have no idea what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot in your case but I had same experience with "ps -ef" in the past (don't remember the exact OS type where I seen it, but my script had to work on any Linux, AIX, Solaris and HP-UX).

The "ps -ef" output might be limited to a certain number of columns when used inside a script executed without a terminal. The user, pid, ppid, cputime columns are dynamic and breaking the format sometimes (when the data is larger then the reserved space).
For example if the PID of the process gets to large then the name of the process might be "cut" so that it doesn't appear in the already limited number of column displayed by "ps -ef" then your monitor script would fail.

You could try to keep the file containing the "ps -ef" output and check if it's this problem. No need to wait for when the issue happens, just check if you have the extra long process names in the file (anything longer then the process you're looking for).

My workaround for this problem is to specify a large enough number of columns to be used, like this: `COLUMNS=8192 ps -ef > file.out` the variable is set just for this 1 purpose.

Comment: I checked my output file with the process listing and it had lines that were 2662 characters long. The process I'm looking for is 123 characters long, so I doubt anything was being truncated. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

I just heard from my server support team that the AIX 7.1 TL4 SP4 patch will fix this! We're installing it on our servers now and hopefully this won't happen again.